# What do we call this drill bit?

Tags: mdf, drill-bit

I was looking at few videos on "how to screw in MDF". I found the one which I needeed. Unfortunately he didn't mention which drill bit he was using.

Here is the photo of it.

[image: Drill bit for MDF]

I am looking to buy it from Lowes/Homedepot. Anyone knows what is it called?

Comment: in most materials you can get similar results by using a bit larger than the screwhead and drilling over the hole until the scraped-away circle is just slightly smaller then the screw head. Tightening the screw will smoosh the last remaining material into place and leave a flush professional result. They are much cheaper at harbor fright, and the quality is fine for the occasional uses homeowners need.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about Harbor Freight. Just now looked and it is way cheaper than home Depot.

Comment: @RakeshJuyal: just be careful, those low prices sometimes come with a serious cost. https://i.imgur.com/oAOR6gr.jpeg and https://i.imgur.com/V7tWNgq.jpeg

Comment: "Harbor Fright" That's a funny typo, @dandavis!!!

Comment: @whatsisname That's a good flow chart. Of course, I'd go directly from "Is this motorized" to "buy something else". I figure I'm buying a HF tool for a specific purpose - so long as it is functional for, and lasts the duration of, the task at hand, I'm happy. If I get additional use out of it, BONUS! That said, I've had some _really_ good deals there on tools that have lasted quite a while.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That bit is a countersinking bit.

[image]

Comment: Note that the one in the OP's picture has a hex-shank so that it can be used in a screwdriver magnetic holder, for ultra-quick changing.